# textbox text to array with C#

Tags: c#, arrays, text

Can anyone help with a little code i want to make array which first index will have first word of textbox text:

array[0] first word of text
array[1] second word of text

can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried anything on this? I could write the function for you, but I don't think that would really help you. Help us help you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string str = "Hello Word Hello" ;
var strarray = str.Split(' ') ;
```

You can replace the str with TextBox.Text...

Comment: thanks guys now how i can see result on label? i mean i have 2 labels and i want to make next: on first label text i want to type first word on second label second word

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method of the string type.

It will *split* your string by a character specification to a string array (`string[]`).

For example:

```
textBox1.Text = "The world is full of fools";
string[] words = textBox1.Text.Split(' ');
foreach(string word in words)
{
  //iterate your words here
}
```

Comment: Did you downvote him for using the same variable names in a one-liner piece of throwaway example code??

Comment: @SirajMansour No one has ownership of any code and I can't see that you  wrote my code.

Answer (score 1):

If they are seperated by spaces :

```
var MyArray = MyTextBox.Text.Split(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

use [.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method like this:

```
var array = textboxText.Split(' ');
```

Comment: @Alexy the split function returns a string[] no need for the .ToArray() in the end

Comment: and no need for var either :) --best practices:if you know you need an int just declare an int as if you know you need(or that you will get and string[])just declare string[].

Comment: @SirajMansour I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

There's a very simple way of doing this:

```
string text = "some text sample";
List<string> ltext = text.Split(' ').ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use the split method,it gets a string array back,you need to pass a char array with the characters to split upon:

```
string[] str = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',', ':', ';', '.' });
```